# How can I do the sequence "If, Else if and Else" in PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

<s>I need somenthing like this:</s>

```
if(list.contains(var)){
    //do something
}else if(list.contains(anotherVar1)){
   //do something
}else if(list.contains(anotherVar2)){
   //do something
}else if(list.contains(anotherVar3)){
   //do something
}else{
  // do something 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I made a mistake. I need this:

```
if(list1.contains(var)){
    //do something
}else if(list2.contains(var)){
    //do something
}else if(list3.contains(var)){
    //do something
}else if(list4.contains(var)){
    //do something
}else{
    // do something 
}
```

I tried this, but the `else` never happens:

```
((member(C,L1)-> print('first'));
(member(C,L2)-> print('second'));
(member(C,L3)-> print('third'));
(member(C,L4)-> print('fourth')));
(print('else')).
```

C is an element and I'm checking if it's member of any of the lists

Comment: I defined `test(C,L1,L2,L3,L4)` with your definition, and `test(1,[],[],[],[])` prints `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm what said by Coredump: you code print "else".

Print to much "else".

I've tried with

```
wichList(C, L1, L2, L3, L4) :-
  ((member(C,L1)-> print('first'));
  (member(C,L2)-> print('second'));
  (member(C,L3)-> print('third'));
  (member(C,L4)-> print('fourth')));
  (print('else')).
```

and, calling `wichList(1, [], [], [], [])`, I see "else".

Anyway, your code is wrong because calling `wichlist(1, [], [1], [], [])`, I see "second", at first, and "else", next.

It's a problem of parentheses: you should close the parentheses of "if" after `print('else')`, not before, so

```
wichList(C, L1, L2, L3, L4) :-
 ((member(C,L1)-> print('first'));
 (member(C,L2)-> print('second'));
 (member(C,L3)-> print('third'));
 (member(C,L4)-> print('fourth'));
 (print('else'))).
```

Answer (score 2):

Your c-like original code require the use of a list and a number of elements, so I suppose that, in your Prolog example, `C` is the list and `L1`, `L2`, `L3` and `L4` are the elements.

But the `member/2` clause in SWI-Prolog, as far I know, require the element in first position and the list in second.

So I suppose that, calling `memeber/2`, you should switch the list with the elements, so

```
((member(L1,C)-> print('first'));
(member(L2,C)-> print('second'));
(member(L3,C)-> print('third'));
(member(L4,C)-> print('fourth')));
(print('else'))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make it very clear, but C is the element and L1,L2,L3 and L4 are lists

Comment: @Éowyn - I see... well... so your c-like example should be something like `if (list1.contains(var)) {} else if (list2.contains(var)) {}...`

Comment: Oh, it's true. I'll fix it

Comment: could you remove all those useless parenthesis ? the code is hideous...

Comment: I second the comment by @CapelliC, and what is more, it seems that the L*s are the lists, and the element is C, so it should be `member(C, L)` and not around.